# Hard disk c drive which has windows vista installed on it, want to secure with restricted permissions

Tags: windows-vista, security, permissions

Hard disk c drive which has Windows Vista installed on it. I want to secure with restricted permissions, so that user or client will not be able to install ot to delete or to modify any programm on it. This will help me to manage customer with less efforts.

How can I do this?

Comment: This question does not really provide sufficient details to elicit an appropriate and well-targeted response.  @Vilas - Please provide more details about your environment, users, and your security goals.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is accomplished simply by creating all users as "Limited Users" and not giving out the password to the built-in Administrator account.  If you're looking to tighten things down more than that, there's a number of additional security options available - but way too many to even begin to cover in detail here.

If the "Limited Users" route is insufficient, and/or you have other requirements that need consideration, please edit the Question to be more detailed.